# Laravel 5.2 redirect

Tags: php, laravel

In my view I'm calling controller fucntion:

```
<a href="{{Redirect::redirectToTest}}" >click</a>
```

Which redirects to another route:

```
public function redirectToTest(){

return redirect()->route('/questions');

}
```

But I'm getting

```
Undefined class constant 'redirectToTest'
```

Plenty boards suggest this and I fail to see why it's not working.

Comment: Try with `Redirect::redirectToTest()` (mind the parenteshis)

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Routing\Redirector

Comment: What is the name of your controller?

Comment: I spelled it wrong, changed to Redirects, but now it says Class 'Redirects' not found. The controller is called Redirects

Comment: Can you show the `Route` that corresponds to your `redirectToTest()` controller method?

Comment: Route::get('/questions', function () {

//method


}

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use

```
<a href="{{ redirect()->route('/questions') }}" >click</a>
```

Comment: My point was to make redirect via controller, nonetheless your version gives Route [/questions] not defined.

Comment: @ŽeniaBogdasic Then why are you calling a static function in your view if is not defined like static? Also if you have a Route not defined error, then you have to define it in your route file. Also you have to provide your path of the Controller in your view

Comment: But it is defined in routes: Route::get('/questions', function ()

Comment: @ŽeniaBogdasic have you named your Route?, **route()** is used when you have named your Route previously . I.e: `Route::get('home' 'HomeController@home)->name('home_route');`. Then you can use `return redirect()->route('home_route');`